# Google structured data dashboard not seeing any data

Tags: google-search-console, rich-snippets, structured-data

When I plug my web page into Google's Rich Snippet Testing Tool it grabs all of the schema.org info I've plugged in correctly, but it says it doesn't detect any structured data when I click on the structured data dashboard.

Is the dashboard buggy still, being so new or is it possible I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: How long have your live site web pages had the rich snippet markups?  The GWT dashboard won't show anything until googlebot has processed the live pages.

Comment: Well, the pages are indexed now but I added the rich snippets to the pages after initially submitting them to google and cannot remember if I resubmitted them.  I'll resubmit them and see what happens in about a week.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with my site. Still doesn't detect any of the structured data.. Its been 4 days now..

Comment: @Joseph, don't start panicking unless it has been well over a week.  I gave it two weeks to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, changes to microdata have often taken a week or more to show up in GWT, even after manually re-submitting affected pages. Assuming the Testing Tool reports correctly functioning code, I wouldn't worry; GWT will show it eventually.

Comment: You guys are correct.  It just took GWT awhile.  Thanks!

Comment: @huzzah Cool! Worth knowing others are getting the same experience.