# How long it takes for Google to see structured data after update?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, structured-data

In Search Console I receive:

> We do not detect any structured data on your site

But the [Structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) shows it all perfectly.

I've added (resubmitted) manually a new sitemap (~100 new pages were added) yesterday, Microdata was added to the page 2 days ago, and JSON-LD format was added 1-2 weeks ago, yet no info.

Maybe there is some errors I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be several reasons causing structured data not appearing in Search Console, besides having them validated. The fact that Google will crawl your page doesn't assure that they will show you the structured data as the other answer suggests. **There is no an estimated time** as this is a process that Google doesn't specify in detail how they handle and validate them [internally](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-rich-snippets#howlong).

> Google does not guarantee that Rich
>   Snippets will show up for search results from a particular site. Here are some reasons that marked-up
>   pages might not be shown with Rich Snippets:The marked-up structured
>   data is not representative of the main content of the page or
>   potentially misleading.Marked-up data is incorrect in a way that
>   the testing tool was not able to catch.Marked-up content is hidden
>   from the user.The site has very few pages (or very few pages with
>   marked-up structured data) and may not be picked up by Google's Rich
>   Snippets system.
>
> Q: How long does it take for rich snippets to be visible? A: Once
>   you've marked up your site's content, Google will discover it the next
>   time we crawl your site (although it may take some time for rich
>   snippets to appear in search results, if we do choose to display rich
>   snippets for your site). If you're marking up your content for rich
>   snippets, you can let us know. Google won't be able to individually
>   reply to your message, but we may use the information you supply to
>   improve our detection and display of marked-up content

If you have validated your structured data, and you are sure they are relevant you only need to wait, check for it in few weeks.

Comment: well at least in 2012 in similar question http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34290/google-structured-data-dashboard-not-seeing-any-data?rq=1 it tooks 2 weeks. I'll take some patience in credit, and wait to check :)

Comment: @LiaMijatovich Lol, fair enough.

Comment: wow, it takes less time )) maybe it helped that I added several pages manually (using Fetch as Google ) and one of that 8 pages appeared in the Search Console->Structured Data

Answer (score 0):

It should be detected as soon as the re-crawl happens.

Do check the correctness of the JSON-LD scripts using the structured data testing tool available in Webmaster.

Comment: as I wrote I've checked validity using "structured data testing tool" provided by google, also I've submited to index selected pages and received "URL and linked pages submitted to index", and checked that same structured data (JSON-LD) are present in the "Downloaded HTTP response"